# Json is sending Überlegung character convert in pentaho different format

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-report-designer, pentaho-design-studio

Json is sending Überlegung character convert in pentaho different format.

Json is sending the value ä

but Pentoho is converting and storing character like this Ã¤

I want to store the data like this ä

Comment: Looks like two different codepages are used. Json is using UTF-8.

Comment: How to resolve this issue

Comment: I don't know Pentaho, but there is probably a setting where you can specify this.

Comment: In the importstep you can set the encoding. What importstep are you using? Is the Json in textfile? or incoming from a service? or read from a db?

Comment: data grid - configured the rest api url  the am using the json input  and am able to see  Überlegung character in the json input results